# Web API POST failed added the FromUri Parameter with RestSharp

Tags: c#, post, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

It seems to me that something strange happens trying to consume a WebApi POST method with RestSharp Client. The code below are for both the Server(WebApi) and the Client respectively .

**Server WebApi**

```
[Route("UserRoles")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IHttpActionResult Post(
    [FromBody] UserroleDto userroleDto,
    [FromUri] string appCode)
{
  return OK();
}
```

And **Test Client**:

```
[TestInitialize()]
public void Initialize()
{
    _restClient = new RestClient("http://localhost:8089");
}

[TestMethod]
public void Can_Store_A_Userrole_Via_REST_WebAPI()
{
    var request = new RestRequest(ApiBasePath, Method.POST);

    request.AddUrlSegment("segment", "UserRoles");
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
    request.AddBody(
        new UserroleDto()
        {
            UserRoleId = -1,
            Role = "Developer"
        });

    request.AddHeader("appCode", AppCode);
    //request.AddParameter("appCode", AppCode);

    _restClient.Execute(request);
}
```

The scenarios are:

1. If I comment out the `[FromUri] string appCode` from the POST method and the `request.AddParameter("appCode", AppCode);` from the Test, the test Pass.
2. If I include the `[FromUri] string appCode` on the POST method and I run the method from POSTMAN, the test Pass.
3. If I include the `[FromUri] string appCode` on the POST method and the `request.AddParameter("appCode", AppCode);` on the Test respectively, the test fail. Error message:
   **Method Not Found on the Controller**

Any advice would be most welcome!

Comment: Scenario 2: what is the url your are querying with POSTMAN like ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'll give an explanation of the experienced behavior in your scenarios. Then I'll provide an solution.

1. If I comment out the [FromUri] string appCode from the POST method
   and the request.AddParameter("appCode", AppCode); from the Test, the
   test Pass.

In this scenario the server does not expect an `appCode` anywhere and the test isn't sending it either. The test seems to pass but I it is a **false positive**. The server doesn't receive an `appCode` at all!

2. If I include the [FromUri] string appCode on the POST
   method and I run the method from POSTMAN, the test Pass.

I guess your using this URL in POSTMAN:

```
http://localhost:8089/UserRoles?appCode=SomeAppCode
```

In this scenario ASP.NET Web API extracts the `appCode` from the URL and the DTO from the body. The server method then executes as expected.

3. If I include the [FromUri] string appCode on the POST method and the
   request.AddParameter("appCode", AppCode); on the Test respectively,
   the test fail. Error message: Method Not Found on the Controller

The reason this fail is that the `appCode` is added to the body. The server however expects it to be in the uri. The framework can therefore not find a method that matches the uri and throws the mentioned error.

**Solution**

I'd change the route and your action if you can:

```
[Route("UserRoles/{appCode}"]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IHttpActionResult Post(string appCode, UserroleDto userroleDto)
{
    return OK();
}
```

With this change the url becomes:

```
http://localhost:8089/UserRoles/SomeAppCode
```

and the body can be put in the body.

Your test code then would be:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Can_Store_A_Userrole_Via_REST_WebAPI()
{
    var request = new RestRequest(ApiBasePath, Method.POST);

    request.AddUrlSegment("segment", "UserRoles");
    request.AddUrlSegment("segment", AppCode);
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
    request.AddBody(
        new UserroleDto()
        {
            UserRoleId = -1,
            Role = "Developer"
        });

    _restClient.Execute(request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Explanation of the behavior you experimented

> 1. *If I commend it out the [FromUri] string appCode from the POST method and the request.AddParameter("appCode", AppCode); from the
>      Test, the test Pass.*

Without the [FromUri], your controller expect to receive AppCode through the request body, which is what RestSharp.AddParameter() actually does. Test pass, all good !

> 2. *If I include the [FromUri] string appCode on the POST method and I run the method from POSTMAN, the test Pass.*

Here, you probably call the appropriate url using POSTMAN, something with a query param in it. Test pass, all good if the url you are querying have the signature you expect it to have.

> 3. *If I include the [FromUri] string appCode on the POST method and the request.AddParameter("appCode", AppCode); on the Test
>      respectively, the test fail. Error message: Method Not Found on the
>      Controller*

Here, it fails because the controller expect to receive AppCode as a query param. (like you probably did it with POSTMAN). But by using RestSharp.AddParameter(), you are probably not sending your query at the right url, thus the error.

## How to solve the problem: define your api route

What you must define is *what should my route look like* ?

Asked differently, one could say *how do I want to query my api ?*

### Option 1: Use query parameter

The [FromUri] will define your controller so it will answer request like:

localhost:8099/UserRoles?appcode=SOMETHING

If this is the url you would like your api to have, RestSharp might be use accordingly:

`var myAppCode="FOO";
var url = "localhost:8099/UserRoles?appCode={appCodeToQuery}";
request.addUrlSegment("appCodeToQuery",myAppCode);`

### Option 2: Use POST body

You could prefer another style for you api route such as:

localhost:8099/UserRoles.

Therefore, you could pass some data using the request body of a POST, something like:

`var myAppCode="FOO";
request.addParameter("appCode",myAppCode);`

which should POST data through request BODY.

### Option 3: Use request header

Also, I doubt that you'd want to pass appCode inside Header. 
It is what RestSharp will do if you call:

`request.AddHeader("appCode", AppCode);`

### Other options ?

Yes, there are other options available to send data to your API. What you will test using RestSharp needs to fit what your controller actually implements.